# D3.js tooltip div takes up space

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have a set of d3 plots set up like the below where a tooltip div is placed beneath the plot div.

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div id="plot1"></div>
              <div id="plot1-tooltip" class="tooltip"></div>
              <div id="plot2"></div>
              <div id="plot2-tooltip" class="tooltip"></div>
              <div id="plot3"></div>
              <div id="plot3-tooltip" class="tooltip"></div>
            </div>
</div>
```

My problem is the lower plots jump to make room when the tooltip becomes visible.  I don't want to use that space for the div because it is eating up real estate that is not actually being used.  Therefore I do not want to fix the problem by making room for the tooltip ahead of time.

the tooltip div position is relative and set by the mouse.  Is there a way to prevent the jump from happening?

**EDIT:**

**things I have tried:**

1. Placed div within svg inside a foreignObject tag, the div never showed up
2. Added 100px to bottom of a class invisible
3. floated the tooltip div left/right

EDIT 2

```js
tooltipData = [1, 2, 3]

svg = d3.select("#plot1").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", 50)

listener = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", 50)
  .attr("fill", "blue")

tooltipDiv = d3.select("#plot1-tooltip")
  .style("position", "relative")
  .style("width", "-webkit-fit-content")
  .style("padding", "5px")

tooltiptable = tooltipDiv.append("table")

tooltiprows = tooltiptable.selectAll("tr")
  .data(tooltipData)
  .enter()
  .append("tr")

svg2 = d3.select("#plot2").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", 50)
  .attr("fill", "blue")

svg2.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", 50)


listener
  .on("mousemove", function() {

    tooltipDiv
      .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")

    tooltiptable.selectAll("tr")
      .html(function(d, i) {
        return "<td>" + d + "</td>"
      })
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.0.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="plot1"></div>
    <div id="plot1-tooltip" class="tooltip"></div>
    <div id="plot2"></div>
    <div id="plot2-tooltip" class="tooltip"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how it all looks exactly, but personally I'd put tooltips inside svg as a `text` tag

Comment: please add enough code to illustrate the problem (additional html, css, js)

Comment: @RachelGallen Minimal example added, there is a lot more going on, but this seems to be the pain point.